# Recaptcha show Image Challenge directly

Tags: recaptcha

recently I am trying to use recaptcha to implement a website. May I ask is there any method to show the image challenge directly instead of clicking any button?

Besides this, is there any method to implement something like [this](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6LdAvUIUAAAAAHjrjmjtNTcXyKm0WKwefLp-dQv9)? But seem no api is called inside of this template.

I understand that this is a fallback function of recaptcha,but how can I get used of it, only limit information can be found on Internet.

Hope to get more information on the fallback function and is there any way to implement somthing similar?